# If Statement Not Working in RobloxLua

Tags: lua, roblox

**Hello Everyone I am wondering why this code gives me an error**
 It's supposed to take some cash of all the players and then add 1 to an int value (stage) update its cost and change the speed value (SpawnDelay) so when he clicks on it again it knows what stage he is on but for some reason this does not work as the if statement shows up as incorrect please help:

```
local stage = script.Parent.stage.Value
local text = script.Parent.Text
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    if stage == 0 then
    for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
v.leaderstats.Cash.Value = v.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 100 

workspace.RedTycoon.Factory.SpawnDelay.Value = 15
text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 200)"
stage =  stage + 1

    elseif stage == 1 then

    for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
v.leaderstats.Cash.Value = v.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 200 

workspace.RedTycoon.Factory.SpawnDelay.Value = 10
text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 500)"
stage =  stage + 1
end
        elseif stage == 2 then

    for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
v.leaderstats.Cash.Value = v.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 500 

workspace.RedTycoon.Factory.SpawnDelay.Value = 8

text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 1000)"


stage =  stage + 1

end)
```

I just tried this

```
local stage = script.Parent.stage.Value
local text = script.Parent.Text
local delaytime = workspace.RedTycoon.Factory.SpawnDelay.Value
text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 100)"
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
if stage == 0 then

delaytime = 15
text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 500)"
stage = stage + 1
for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 100
    end
end



elseif stage == 1 then
    delaytime = 10
text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 1000)"
stage = stage + 1
for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 500
    end
end


elseif stage == 2 then
    delaytime = 10
    text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 1500)"
stage = stage + 1
for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 1000
    end
end


elseif stage == 3 then
    text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 2000)"
    delaytime = 8
stage = stage + 1
for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 1500
    end
end


elseif stage == 4 then
    delaytime = 4
    text = "Upgrade Speed            (Cost = 20000)"
stage = stage + 1
for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 2000
    end

end

elseif stage == 5 then
    delaytime = 2
    text = "No More Upgrades Avalible"  
stage = stage + 1
for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value -  20000
    end

end

else
    text = "Just for being annoying here you have 1 less cash:"

for _, player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
           player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - 1
        end

end
        wait(4)
        text = "No More Upgrades Avalible"  


        end

end)
```

Didn't work

Answer (score 1):

After removing all the excess code statements, we can see that the code structure is, at the very least, missing three `end` keywords.

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function ()
    if stage == 0 then
        for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        -- missing end
    elseif stage == 1 then
        for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do

        end
    elseif stage == 2 then
        for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        -- missing end
    -- missing
end)
```